# Is a car with a bumper sticker subclass of a car?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, decorator

I am not an expert in OOPS and or design patterns.

I have come across this situation: Is a car with a bumper sticker subclass of a car?

If not then how can I add dynamic properties to instance of an object? For example a car, a car with bumper sticker etc.

Not all cars come with a bumper sticker. One can add a bumper sticker and even more than one bumper sticker. I can not implement a sticker with car, afaik, implementing me will force me to add stickers. A bumper sticker on a car is one new property that came into existence after car (object?) was created.

Comment: Depends on your opinion of bumper stickers. It would be a pain to have to subclass for every minute variation in cars (spoilers, snow tires, antennae). The question isn't really answerable.

Comment: No - a car with a sticker is still a car - maybe one of its attributes changed, but it's not a subclass, I'd argue.

Comment: Please answer the following questions: Can every car have a bumper sticker? How does the behavior of a car with bumper sticker differ from the behavior of a car without one? What change in behavior is expected if a car has several of them?

Comment: @Rafe Kettler: That pain is solved with the decorator pattern, see my answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [Decorator Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) for cases like this. It will allow you to "add dynamic properties to instance of an object" which is what you mentioned, you can add any amout of stickers or any other property, in all combinations possible by "decorating" your `car` class.

Comment: thanks :) I am going to spend some time with the coffee example

Answer (score 2):

The changes to Car you are talking about are dynamic attributes. Personally I would implement a collection of Accessories in the Car class, one of which would be a BumperSticker.

You can then add and remove Accessories without having to subclass Car for all the options available.

If you go down the inheritance route think about the situation when a car has a BumperSticker and Spoilers, you would have multiple inheritance which is frowned upon in C++ and not available in other languages.

Comment: It's also frowned upon *logically* in this case, because a car with bumper stickers and a car with spoilers are not two different types of cars. They're attributes of a single type car.

Comment: exactly, a bumper sticker is just "another" attribute or property of a car that your car may have and mine may lack

Answer (score 1):

If the bumper sticker is a common thing in your case, you can set a boolean attribute (true/false) or a string if that's it in your case.

If the bumper sticker is complicated to be a class of it self, perhaps the Car should Implement the sticker? (I am referring to Implementation in Java here)

As for Dynamic, would a database table of properties relating to the car be acceptable?

Comment: I think the key is, as above, is the bumper sticker complex enough to require a class of its own?  Are you recording that a bumper sticker exists or the details of it?  Otherwise just have a boolean for 0 or more stickers, integer for a count, etc.

Comment: this wont lead to a good design, bumper sticker is totally optional, but can be had on a car or even bike, if its small enough

Answer (score 1):

Don't overcomplicate this.

```
class Car
{
public:
    bool hasBumperSticker() const { return m_hasBumperSticker; }

private:
    bool m_hasBumperSticker;
};
```

Or, if the bumper sticker has its own properties:

```
class Car
{
public:
    bool hasBumperSticker() const { return m_bumperSticker != 0; }

private:
    BumperSticker* m_hasBumperSticker;
};
```

Comment: bumper sticker is an example, I can add many other properties, so according to you, I will need to have a hasProprtyXYZ() method for all those properties, here is some thing that just stuck me
`code`
class car{ 
 private propertyarray;
 public hasProperty(propertyname){ return (isset(this.proprtyarray[propertyname])? true : false);}
 public setProperty(propertyname, value){ this.proprtyarray[propertyname]=value;}
}
`code`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, when you buy a car you choose the car itself and a set of options (music, interior, etc). As in a real life you can introduce 'options' in your car class. In a simple case it looks like (C++):

```
class Car {

    enum CarOptions {
      Bumper,
      ...
    };

    ...

    int options() const { return m_options; }
    void setOptions(int options) { m_options = options }

    ...
};

Car c;
c.setOptions(c.options() | Car::Bumper);
```

Of course, this solution has it's own pros and cons, as any other.

Comment: can you list down pros and cons?

Comment: pro: Simple; con: Only a boolean indication that an option has been set, no other information can be stored (such as what is printed on the sticker)

Comment: Pros: it's very simple to use and it's useful when you have a bunch of options (not 1 or 2 but 10 or 20). Cons: if  Bumper is complicated itself you probably should use other solution. So it depends.

Comment: You can even write 'addOption' function to make option addition easy. Like: `void addOption(CarOption option) { m_options |= option; }` and then use it `Car c; c.addOption(Car::Bumper); ... c.addOption(Car::Music);`